# Why INSERT IGNORE insert rows with same PRIMARY KEY?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, prestashop

Im trying to migrate data from 2 tables to one and in different databases, with this query:

```
 INSERT IGNORE INTO 
  db2.customer(id, firstname,lastname,phone)

  SELECT customer.id,customer.firstname,customer.lastname,address.phone

  FROM db1.customer
  JOIN db1.address 
  ON customer.id = address.id_customer;
```

I take data from db1 (customer & address tables) and insert in db2 (customer table) and works fine.
But

1. If not use IGNORE I get an error for duplicate Primary key

   ```
     INSERT INTO 
        db2.customer(id, firstname,...
   ```
2. If I use IGNORE, customers that have more than one address are inserted twice.

[image]

Why don't IGNORE statement skip the duplicate values?

I tried using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE but in this case (2 different databases) I dont know why dont work.

db1 is a Prestashop database:

ps_address

[image]

ps_customer

[image]

And db2 is a custom database:

customer

How Can I do for skip (or update) rows with id already contained?

I tried too with:

```
 INSERT INTO 
  db2.customer(id, firstname,lastname,phone)

  SELECT DISTINCT 
  customer.id,customer.firstname,customer.lastname,address.phone

  FROM db1.customer
  JOIN db1.address 
  ON customer.id = address.id_customer;
```

But doesn't work

Best regards

Comment: The column `id_customer` is defined as an auto-increment primary key.  You should not be providing a value for such a column.

Comment: Are you saying that the customer ID is the primary key of the customer table, but after running your insert statement there are duplicate customer IDs in that table? That should not be possible.

Comment: As Gordon pointed out, do not parse anything to auto incremented id's. They will set the id's themselves appropriately. If you need an id after a specific insert to carry over somewhere else, then you can use `LAST_INSERT_ID()`. Since you tagged prestashop, you can also use this on a PHP level, `Db::getInstance()->Insert_ID();`. If you need to avoid duplicates, use the keyword `DISTINCT` in your statement.

Comment: @Martin I tried too. But with `SELECT DISTINCT` still duplicates appear

Comment: @GordonLinoff I know. In my table custom table Customers my primary key isn't autoincrement. I need the id's

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: Again: `id` is the primary key of the table `db2.customer`, so there cannot be two rows with the same `id`. But after running your insert statement, the table does contain two rows with the `id` 31755 in spite of `id` being the primary key. Yes?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yes. You can chek screenshot of my hedisql. IGNORE statement do this

Comment: Then your MySQL version is buggy. The primary key is supposed to prevent duplicate rows. `IGNORE` is supposed to dismiss rows that would violate the primary key constraint. Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=573f43afe4853ba89ebc831524253672

Comment: Please provide the table definition for db2.customer. I assume the 2 screenshots you have provided are for the db1 tables?